# ¿ Como llenar un array de objetos hashtable en C# (VS2008)?

Tags: c#

Necesito crear un array que contenga n objetos hashtable() o que contenga n objetos.
No se como declarar este array o arrayList en C# (VS2008)

```
Hashtable myHT = new Hashtable();
Array myArray = // ¿ Como declararlo ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trabajar con arrays, deberías hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
//Defino un array de Hastable con 10 posiciones 
Hashtable[] array = new Hashtable[10];

//Lo recorro e inicializo cada objeto dentro dle array
for(int i = 0;i < array.Length ; i++)
{
   array[i] = new Hashtable();
}
```

Y ya podes trabajar con tu array de `Hashtable`, sin embargo, si no tenes requisitos muy puntuales, sería mejor que trabajes con `List<T>` ya que es mucho más práctico.

Un ejemplo sería

```
List<Hashtable> Lista = new List<Hashtable>();

Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();

//Trabajas con el objeto y luego podes añadirlo a la lista, sin necesidad de definir un tamaño
Lista.add(hashTable);
```

**Edit**

Si lo que buscas es usar un Array en lugar de una lista (y no sabes lo cuál es el tamaño que tendrá) podes hacer lo siguiente

```
//Definis una lista
List<Hashtable> Lista = new List<Hashtable>(); 
Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
//La llenas según necesidad
Lista.add(hashTable);
//Definis el array le asignas la lista utilizando ToArray()
Hashtable[] hashTableArray = Lista.ToArray();
```

Comment: Al array se le deben añadir los objetos dinámicamente por lo que no tiene tamaño fijo.  ¿ Como lo declaro sin tamaño fijo ?. Por otra parte List no me lo reconoce en VS2008

Comment: Perdon si que reconoce el "List" no tenia puesto using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: @Popularfan ahí edite la pregunta explicandote como usar un `Array` con un tamaño dinámico con ayuda de una lista

Comment: De todas maneras, como te digo en la respuesta, si no tenes requerimentos de performance muy específicos, usa `List<T>` que te va a solucionar varios problemas :D

Comment: También puedes usar `ArrayList` te dejo el [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/41107z8a.aspx) con mas información.

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, gracias !